# XFS in-memory corruption after hibernate

Tags: raid, hibernate, gentoo, mdadm, xfs

I am constantly getting the below errors with XFS filesystem present on software raid-1 which was then converted to 3-disk raid-5. Errors happen exclusively after hibernate, normally either immediately or a few minutes past. `dmesg` tells (full `dmesg` output is here: http://bpaste.net/show/130895/):

```
[155389.814032] PM: restore of devices complete after 1700.425 msecs
[155389.814783] Restarting tasks ... done.
[155390.161993] r8168: enp2s0: link up
[155392.181215] r8168: enp2s0: link up
[155398.859967] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page present
[155398.859972] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[155398.876927] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page present
[155398.876932] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[155398.877945]  sdh:
[155690.215471] XFS: Internal error XFS_WANT_CORRUPTED_RETURN at line 342 of file fs/xfs/xfs_alloc.c.  Caller 0xffffffff812049d1

[155690.215478] CPU: 5 PID: 17532 Comm: kworker/5:0 Tainted: P           O 3.10.7-gentoo #1
[155690.215481] Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./M5A97 R2.0, BIOS 0601 07/17/2012
[155690.215490] Workqueue: xfsalloc xfs_bmapi_allocate_worker
[155690.215493]  ffffffff81565b8a 0000000000000071 ffffffff81201c57 ffff880418328000
[155690.215498]  ffff880418328270 ffff8803124ee460 0000000081206839 0000000000000800
[155690.215502]  ffff8803990ffd18 ffff880418328000 0000000000000800 0000000000000800
[155690.215506] Call Trace:
[155690.215514]  [<ffffffff81565b8a>] ? dump_stack+0xd/0x17
[155690.215520]  [<ffffffff81201c57>] ? xfs_alloc_fixup_trees+0x1e7/0x370
[155690.215524]  [<ffffffff812049d1>] ? xfs_alloc_ag_vextent_near+0xa21/0xd90
[155690.215528]  [<ffffffff81204dfd>] ? xfs_alloc_ag_vextent+0xbd/0xf0
[155690.215532]  [<ffffffff81205aa8>] ? xfs_alloc_vextent+0x478/0x800
[155690.215536]  [<ffffffff812139d6>] ? xfs_bmap_btalloc_nullfb+0x316/0x350
[155690.215541]  [<ffffffff8121721a>] ? xfs_bmap_btalloc+0x31a/0x770
[155690.215546]  [<ffffffff810459f8>] ? internal_add_timer+0x18/0x50
[155690.215551]  [<ffffffff810459f8>] ? internal_add_timer+0x18/0x50
[155690.215556]  [<ffffffff81217c4d>] ? __xfs_bmapi_allocate+0xcd/0x2e0
[155690.215560]  [<ffffffff81217e9c>] ? xfs_bmapi_allocate_worker+0x3c/0x70
[155690.215566]  [<ffffffff810535d0>] ? process_one_work+0x150/0x480
[155690.215570]  [<ffffffff81053f3a>] ? manage_workers.isra.26+0x1aa/0x2b0
[155690.215575]  [<ffffffff81054154>] ? worker_thread+0x114/0x370
[155690.215579]  [<ffffffff81054040>] ? manage_workers.isra.26+0x2b0/0x2b0
[155690.215584]  [<ffffffff8105a163>] ? kthread+0xb3/0xc0
[155690.215588]  [<ffffffff81060000>] ? async_run_entry_fn+0xf0/0x120
[155690.215593]  [<ffffffff8105a0b0>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60
[155690.215598]  [<ffffffff815708ec>] ? ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[155690.215603]  [<ffffffff8105a0b0>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60
[155690.215619] XFS (md1): page discard on page ffffea000d1df580, inode 0x22057716, offset 8323072.
[155720.362810] XFS: Internal error XFS_WANT_CORRUPTED_RETURN at line 342 of file fs/xfs/xfs_alloc.c.  Caller 0xffffffff812049d1

<...> (a big bunch of similar errors skipped)

[156100.313075] CPU: 4 PID: 27035 Comm: kworker/4:2 Tainted: P           O 3.10.7-gentoo #1
[156100.313078] Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./M5A97 R2.0, BIOS 0601 07/17/2012
[156100.313099] Workqueue: xfsalloc xfs_bmapi_allocate_worker
[156100.313103]  ffffffff81565b8a 0000000000000071 ffffffff81201c57 ffff88041a811d00
[156100.313107]  ffff88041a811dd0 0000000000000001 000000007f95bfd8 0000000000000002
[156100.313111]  ffff88017f95bd18 ffff88041a811d00 0000000000000001 0000000000000001
[156100.313115] Call Trace:
[156100.313123]  [<ffffffff81565b8a>] ? dump_stack+0xd/0x17
[156100.313129]  [<ffffffff81201c57>] ? xfs_alloc_fixup_trees+0x1e7/0x370
[156100.313133]  [<ffffffff8120491a>] ? xfs_alloc_ag_vextent_near+0x96a/0xd90
[156100.313138]  [<ffffffff81204dfd>] ? xfs_alloc_ag_vextent+0xbd/0xf0
[156100.313141]  [<ffffffff81205aa8>] ? xfs_alloc_vextent+0x478/0x800
[156100.313146]  [<ffffffff812139d6>] ? xfs_bmap_btalloc_nullfb+0x316/0x350
[156100.313150]  [<ffffffff8121721a>] ? xfs_bmap_btalloc+0x31a/0x770
[156100.313156]  [<ffffffff810459f8>] ? internal_add_timer+0x18/0x50
[156100.313161]  [<ffffffff810459f8>] ? internal_add_timer+0x18/0x50
[156100.313165]  [<ffffffff81217c4d>] ? __xfs_bmapi_allocate+0xcd/0x2e0
[156100.313170]  [<ffffffff81217e9c>] ? xfs_bmapi_allocate_worker+0x3c/0x70
[156100.313176]  [<ffffffff810535d0>] ? process_one_work+0x150/0x480
[156100.313186]  [<ffffffff81054154>] ? worker_thread+0x114/0x370
[156100.313208]  [<ffffffff81054040>] ? manage_workers.isra.26+0x2b0/0x2b0
[156100.313214]  [<ffffffff8105a163>] ? kthread+0xb3/0xc0
[156100.313228]  [<ffffffff81060000>] ? async_run_entry_fn+0xf0/0x120
[156100.313239]  [<ffffffff8105a0b0>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60
[156100.313249]  [<ffffffff815708ec>] ? ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[156100.313258]  [<ffffffff8105a0b0>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60
[156100.313275] XFS (md1): page discard on page ffffea0008f25340, inode 0x22057716, offset 8499200.
[156155.266439] XFS: Internal error XFS_WANT_CORRUPTED_GOTO at line 1617 of file fs/xfs/xfs_alloc.c.  Caller 0xffffffff81205f1c

[156155.266443] CPU: 4 PID: 32209 Comm: QThread Tainted: P           O 3.10.7-gentoo #1
[156155.266444] Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./M5A97 R2.0, BIOS 0601 07/17/2012
[156155.266446]  ffffffff81565b8a 0000000000000070 ffffffff81202e8c ffff88041b3c3980
[156155.266448]  ffff88041821ee40 0000000000000000 0000000000000003 ffff88041b3c3980
[156155.266449]  ffff880417bf6800 0000000000000000 ffff8801eac77c5c 0000000800000000
[156155.266451] Call Trace:
[156155.266456]  [<ffffffff81565b8a>] ? dump_stack+0xd/0x17
[156155.266460]  [<ffffffff81202e8c>] ? xfs_free_ag_extent+0x53c/0x850
[156155.266461]  [<ffffffff81205f1c>] ? xfs_free_extent+0xec/0x130
[156155.266463]  [<ffffffff8120128e>] ? kmem_zone_alloc+0x5e/0xe0
[156155.266465]  [<ffffffff8121939a>] ? xfs_bmap_finish+0x16a/0x1b0
[156155.266467]  [<ffffffff812396b3>] ? xfs_itruncate_extents+0x103/0x320
[156155.266469]  [<ffffffff811ff4ce>] ? xfs_inactive+0x32e/0x450
[156155.266470]  [<ffffffff811fcb8b>] ? xfs_fs_evict_inode+0x4b/0x130
[156155.266473]  [<ffffffff8112ca87>] ? evict+0xa7/0x1b0
[156155.266476]  [<ffffffff8112143c>] ? do_unlinkat+0x19c/0x1f0
[156155.266477]  [<ffffffff81118f53>] ? SyS_newstat+0x23/0x30
[156155.266480]  [<ffffffff81570992>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[156155.266483] XFS (md1): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x8) called from line 916 of file fs/xfs/xfs_bmap.c.  Return address = 0xffffffff812193d3
[156155.445552] XFS (md1): Corruption of in-memory data detected.  Shutting down filesystem
[156155.445557] XFS (md1): Please umount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
[156160.004902] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156190.132832] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156220.260719] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156250.388550] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156280.516400] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156310.644246] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156340.772019] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156370.899941] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156401.027736] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156431.155576] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156461.283434] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156491.411366] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156521.539215] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156551.666963] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156581.795447] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156611.922687] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156642.050630] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156672.178470] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156702.306332] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156732.434176] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[156762.561988] XFS (md1): xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
```

Kernel version is 3.10.7, saw the same error on 3.8.13. Note that md1 is not the only RAID device used for XFS filesystem: I also hold / on RAID1 (SSD+HDD).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a i915 card, try updating the kernel, there was several reports that KMS on those cards caused [memory corruption on hibernation/resume](http://codemonkey.org.uk/2012/03/12/i915-hibernate-memory-corruption/)

You can try to test with i915.modeset=0 to see if the problem disappears... if it does, its probably the same problem and should have been already fixed in more recent kernels

If you don't have a i915, it's unknown what might be the problem.. try playing with the BIOS/power settings, hibernate without X to test another graphic card related corruption, run memtest86 to check real memory problems, try recent or older kernels... and probably open a distro/kernel bug if the problem is reproducible.

Comment: I do not have i915. Playing with any settings will not work because it is not reproducible. I.e. I had not hit it at least in a month, but I have no idea whether it was because I updated the kernel and it fixed things or because necessary preconditions were not met.

Comment: If you upgrade the kernel and didn't see this since, it was probably a kernel bug that was later fixed.

Comment: I have experienced this some time after the update, so it was not fixed at least then. Next suspect is hardware problem: I found that the newest 2 TB HDD I have installed despite being the newest emits loads of read errors. Main problem is that the filesystem affected by this fact was *not* located on that HDD (not until I thought it is good idea to place it on the RAID5 with one device being a partition on that drive), though the one that was was XFS as well. At least I never experienced this bug after replacing almost all disk drives, but it is too early to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar call traces with 3.16.5 after resume from hibernate. I've switched to ext4 and seen no issues with it.

My setup used xfs roofs and file swap (not swap partition). Suspend and hibernate worked fine and resume works ok for both except for some call traces from hibernate.

The system is semi-usable until moderate file ops begin. The litmus test is to run:

```
# tail -f /var/log/messages
```

and then hibernate.
After resume the system is non responsive. With ext4 I see no call traces and the system looks ok.

I've suspected some issues with xfs when I've seen this:

```
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841446] general protection fault: 0000 [#2] SMP 
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841514] Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(O) vboxnetflt(O) vboxdrv(O) x86_pkg_temp_thermal
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841618] CPU: 1 PID: 13937 Comm: mozStorage #10 Tainted: G      D    O  3.16.5-gentoo #22
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841702] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. G56JK/G56JK, BIOS G56JK.201 05/13/2014
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841782] task: ffff8800c5658880 ti: ffff88011262c000 task.ti: ffff88011262c000
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841854] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8113ae68>]  [<ffffffff8113ae68>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x58/0x130
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.841947] RSP: 0018:ffff88011262fb60  EFLAGS: 00010282
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842000] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffea00021c47c0 RCX: 0000000000180d5c
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842069] RDX: 0000000000180d5b RSI: 0000000000008050 RDI: ffff88012a44ca00
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842138] RBP: ffff88011262fb90 R08: 0000000000016300 R09: ffffea00021c4800
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842208] R10: 0000000000000a95 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00f7000000f60000
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842277] R13: 0000000000008050 R14: ffff88012a44ca00 R15: ffffffff81171e4c
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842348] FS:  00007f083e0fc700(0000) GS:ffff88012ee40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842427] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842484] CR2: 00007f08403780e3 CR3: 000000011dc39000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842553] Stack:
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842576]  0000000000000483 ffffea00021c47c0 0000000000000000 0000000000001000
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842661]  ffffea00021c47c0 0000000000000000 ffff88011262fba8 ffffffff81171e4c
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842745]  ffff88011262fbd8 ffff88011262fbe8 ffffffff81172102 0000000100000000
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842829] Call Trace:
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842867]  [<ffffffff81171e4c>] alloc_buffer_head+0x1c/0x60
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842926]  [<ffffffff81172102>] alloc_page_buffers+0x32/0xb0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.842987]  [<ffffffff81173179>] create_empty_buffers+0x19/0xc0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.843048]  [<ffffffff81173267>] create_page_buffers+0x47/0x50
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.843108]  [<ffffffff811742c8>] __block_write_begin+0x68/0x430
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.846472]  [<ffffffff811009d9>] ? lru_cache_add+0x9/0x10
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.849840]  [<ffffffff810f39f8>] ? add_to_page_cache_lru+0x48/0x70
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.852926]  [<ffffffff811eeef0>] ? __xfs_get_blocks+0x4f0/0x4f0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.855809]  [<ffffffff810f3ca5>] ? pagecache_get_page+0x95/0x1e0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.858662]  [<ffffffff811edbec>] xfs_vm_write_begin+0x4c/0xe0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.861460]  [<ffffffff8114cb61>] ? terminate_walk+0x41/0x50
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.863974]  [<ffffffff810f351d>] generic_perform_write+0xbd/0x1b0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.866483]  [<ffffffff811fa3e0>] xfs_file_buffered_aio_write.isra.9+0x100/0x1b0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.869005]  [<ffffffff811fa50e>] xfs_file_write_iter+0x7e/0x120
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.871518]  [<ffffffff81142bcc>] new_sync_write+0x7c/0xb0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.874024]  [<ffffffff81143322>] vfs_write+0xb2/0x1f0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.876520]  [<ffffffff81143e71>] SyS_write+0x41/0xb0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.878980]  [<ffffffff81142e43>] ? SyS_lseek+0x43/0xb0
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.881405]  [<ffffffff81783e92>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.883610] Code: 8b 06 65 4c 03 04 25 a8 cd 00 00 49 8b 50 08 4d 8b 20 49 8b 40 10 4d 85 e4 74 68 48 85 c0 74 63 49 63 46 20 48 8d 4a 01 4d 8b 06 <49> 8b 1c 04 4c 89 e0 65 49 0f c7 08 0f 94 c0 84 c0 74 c1 49 63 
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.886116] RIP  [<ffffffff8113ae68>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x58/0x130
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.888473]  RSP <ffff88011262fb60>
Dec 20 23:57:58 localhost kernel: [ 9053.907290] ---[ end trace a68ba9204a0e3b64 ]---
```

These on the other hand were seen more often:

```
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.619889] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.619914] Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(O) vboxnetflt(O) vboxdrv(O) x86_pkg_temp_thermal
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.619948] CPU: 6 PID: 10285 Comm: udevadm Tainted: G           O  3.16.5-gentoo #22
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.619973] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. G56JK/G56JK, BIOS G56JK.201 05/13/2014
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.619999] task: ffff8801292e2a80 ti: ffff8800c3754000 task.ti: ffff8800c3754000
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620023] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8115a6d8>]  [<ffffffff8115a6d8>] __d_lookup_rcu+0x78/0x160
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620054] RSP: 0018:ffff8800c3757c68  EFLAGS: 00010206
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620071] RAX: 0000000000000004 RBX: 006b0000006a0000 RCX: 000000000000000d
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620094] RDX: 0000000000690000 RSI: ffff8800c3757e60 RDI: ffff88012a0be540
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620116] RBP: ffff8800c3757ca8 R08: ffff8800c3757dec R09: ffff8800c3757ccc
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620138] R10: ffff880129a0202f R11: 0000000000000004 R12: ffff88012a0be540
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620160] R13: 006b00000069fff8 R14: 00000004d16f3f17 R15: ffff8800c3757e60
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620183] FS:  00007f50c54097c0(0000) GS:ffff88012ef80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620208] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620226] CR2: 00007fff115e7e10 CR3: 000000009655d000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620248] Stack:
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620255]  000280d00000ffff 0000000000000001 0000000000000246 ffff8800c3757df8
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620282]  ffff8800c3757d70 ffff8800c3757df8 ffff8800c3757e50 ffff88012a0be540
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620309]  ffff8800c3757cf8 ffffffff8114cbdf ffff8801292e2a80 ffff8800c4bca020
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620336] Call Trace:
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620348]  [<ffffffff8114cbdf>] lookup_fast+0x3f/0x2c0
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620367]  [<ffffffff81150e02>] do_last+0xa2/0x1130
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620385]  [<ffffffff8114dc89>] ? link_path_walk+0x69/0x890
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620405]  [<ffffffff81151f46>] path_openat+0xb6/0x630
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620423]  [<ffffffff81152c25>] do_filp_open+0x35/0x80
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620442]  [<ffffffff8115ea0d>] ? __alloc_fd+0x7d/0x120
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620460]  [<ffffffff81142513>] do_sys_open+0x123/0x220
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620479]  [<ffffffff81142629>] SyS_open+0x19/0x20
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620497]  [<ffffffff81783e92>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620516] Code: 83 e3 fe 0f 84 b2 00 00 00 4c 89 f0 48 c1 e8 20 49 89 c3 eb 12 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 1b 48 85 db 0f 84 94 00 00 00 4c 8d 6b f8 <8b> 53 fc 4c 39 63 10 75 e7 48 83 7b 08 00 74 e0 83 e2 fe 41 f6 
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620635] RIP  [<ffffffff8115a6d8>] __d_lookup_rcu+0x78/0x160
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.620656]  RSP <ffff8800c3757c68>
Dec 21 13:38:12 localhost kernel: [ 3276.627506] ---[ end trace 74da4d08df847136 ]---
```

Comment: It looks like a different error: a) my trace always contains `dump_stack` at the top and b) system is not “not responsive”. It is completely responsive, except that trying to read or write to crashed FS causes IO error which in turn may cause some applications to crash simply because they are badly coded and do not expect these errors.

Comment: yes the traces are not identical but the context ( gentoo, xfs, hibernate) is sufficiently similar to warrant a reference. I guess I could have added a question by itself to record the issue.